# Combine two lambda expressions without intermediate step

Tags: java, lambda, expression

I'm trying to write a lambda expression that sorts a string array by string length by using a single lambda expression variable. This is what I have come up with (using two)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Consumer<String[]> sort =  s -> Arrays.sort(s, (String s1, String s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length());

    Consumer<String[]> print = sort.andThen(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));

    print.accept(strings);

}
```

Is there a way to combine sort and print so that they are just one expression? I have tried this:

```
Consumer<String[]> print = (s -> Arrays.sort(s, (String s1, String s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length())).andThen(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
```

But I'm just getting

```
String s1, String s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length()
```

marked red saying "Cannot infer functional interface type". Is what I'm trying even possible? I know it's a pretty useless this worrying about but now I'm curious if this is possible.

Comment: If you are printing strings then you don't need to do `Arrays.toString`

Comment: @AdriaanKoster He's printing the array though.

Comment: Ah yes, now I see. tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas in Java always need to target a functional interface (an interface with only a single abstract method). In your case, that is the `Consumer`-interface.

The reason you get the error when you chain the two lambdas together with `andThen` is because the compiler doesn't know which functional interface the first lambda is targetting. So it doesn't know which `andThen` function to call. It only knows that the whole expression should result in a `Consumer`.

To fix it, you would need to cast the first lambda to `Consumer<String[]>`. Like this:

```
Consumer<String[]> print = ((Consumer<String[]>) s -> Arrays.sort(s, (String s1, String s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length()))
    .andThen(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
```

Comment: hi, could you elaborate on "the compiler doesn't know which functional interface the first lambda is targetting"? how is it that the compiler doesnt know that the first lambda is for ```Consumer<String[]>``` without the explicit cast?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Anyone could create a similar functional interface like `Consumer` as well, and the lambda would fit both interfaces. There is nothing special with the built-in functional interfaces in `java.util.function` that causes the compiler to pick `Consumer` automatically.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using :

```
        Arrays.stream(s).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```